# cl.exe is not able to compile a simple test program VS2017

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, cl.exe

I am trying to compile my c++ project on VS2017 with CMake (I am using windows 10 x64).
Here is my `tasks.json`:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "CMake Debug",
        "type": "shell",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/build"
        },
        "command": "CMake",
        "args": [
            "-G",
            "NMake Makefiles",
            "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug",
            ".."
        ],
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "Make",
        "type": "shell",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/build"
        },
        "command": "nmake",
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
```

}

And when I run the CMake Debug task, I got the following error:

```
Executing task: CMake -G 'NMake Makefiles' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .. <

-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x86/cl.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x86/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/EIP/Cryptagora-prisma/monitoring_tool/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"nmake" "/nologo" "cmTC_8304c\fast"
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe" -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_8304c.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_8304c.dir\build
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_8304c.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
        C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2017\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1416~1.270\bin\Hostx64\x86\cl.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_8304c.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj   -c C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\EIP\Cryptagora-prisma\monitoring_tool\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
    NMAKE : fatal error U1045: Úchec de la gÚnÚration dynamiqueá: Invalid argument
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"'á: code retour '0x2'
    Stop.




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/EIP/Cryptagora-prisma/monitoring_tool/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/EIP/Cryptagora-prisma/monitoring_tool/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

This was working perfectly yesterday.

Comment: If you are developing on windows, you will have a much smoother experience if you avoid cmake completely.

Comment: Please, paste the log in the **textual** form, not as an *image*. This is a requirement of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why should I avoid CMake on windows? What else could I use?

Comment: Try in a developer command prompt, rather than a normal one?

Comment: You could just use plain old visual studio. The reason being that you are introducing a huge intermediate layer that is completely unnecessary. Second the mere fact that you are posting here with a problem.

Comment: Can correctly compile with Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017, but can't manage to compile with CMake and command prompt inside VS Code (which is also Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017)

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem a few months ago, and had to revert to an older version of cmake. Specifically downgrade to 3.12.4.